# How do I display Non-English letters in my flask web application?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, flask, utf-8, google-translate

I am translating some English text into local Indian languages using 'googletrans' Python module. It is perfectly translating into the selected language in development version, but in my production version it is displaying as '????' question marks. What are the possible reasons

**Development results:**

[image: Development results]

**Production results:**

[image]

**Update:**
After more digging I found its happening in DB level. I queried the text data that I inserted into the database. This is what I found in  my production database and in my local database. Both are Mysql(MariaDB in production) databases.
[image]
[image]

Comment: You'll have to publish the minimal source code. The issue could be on the browser level. What results are you getting if you "curl" your page instead of opening it.

Comment: @avloss I am testing both local and production on the same browser, I think there is no wrong with the source code, that is the reason I didn't include. I think the problem is with my hosting, I am not sure.

Comment: How are you deploying your code?

Comment: @avloss I am deploying through github. I am pushing to github and then pulling through it.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to the Collation variable of my table columns is set to 'latin1_swedish_ci', I changed them into 'utf8_general_ci' and the problem is solved.

[image]

**UPDATE:**
I read few previous answers about this situation, they suggest 'utf8_unicode_ci' in place of 'utf8_general_ci'.